Unable to connect to wifi on my Ubuntu 22.04
Here are some of the log messages:
dmesg:
`gnome-shell' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for Wi-Fi 7 hardware; use nl80211
[   37.086239] wlo1: authenticate with e6:e1:33:77:01:cd
[   37.212335] wlo1: send auth to e6:e1:33:77:01:cd (try 1/3)
[   37.227311] wlo1: send auth to e6:e1:33:77:01:cd (try 2/3)
[   37.242256] wlo1: send auth to e6:e1:33:77:01:cd (try 3/3)
[   37.257037] wlo1: authentication with e6:e1:33:77:01:cd timed out
[   49.480984] wlo1: authenticate with e6:e1:33:77:01:cd
[   49.608266] wlo1: send auth to e6:e1:33:77:01:cd (try 1/3)
[   49.623666] wlo1: send auth to e6:e1:33:77:01:cd (try 2/3)
[   49.638856] wlo1: send auth to e6:e1:33:77:01:cd (try 3/3)
[   49.654081] wlo1: authentication with e6:e1:33:77:01:cd timed out

Getting something like above
Here is all the wireless Info Log:
########## wireless info START ##########
Report from: 14 May 2024 18:26 IST +0530
Booted last: 14 May 2024 00:00 IST +0530
Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

##### kernel ############################
Linux 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, acpi_backlight=native, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 16)
    DeviceName: OnBoard Enthernets
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:88de]

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852AE 802.11ax PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8852]
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e1]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0408:5365 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2717:ff88 Xiaomi Inc. Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS + ADB)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:2852 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6488064  0
mac80211             1720320  2 rtw89_core,rtw89_pci
hp_wmi                 28672  0
sparse_keymap          12288  1 hp_wmi
platform_profile       12288  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               12288  0
cfg80211             1323008  4 wl,rtw89_core,mac80211,rtw89_8852a
libarc4                12288  1 mac80211
wmi                    40960  3 hp_wmi,video,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    altname enp2s0
3: enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.233.147/24 brd 192.168.233.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
       valid_lft 3324sec preferred_lft 3324sec
    inet6 fe80::1fc1:6e89:6531:59dc/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlo1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlo1' [IF3]> brd <MAC address>
    altname wlp3s0

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.233.117 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> scope link metric 1000 
192.168.233.0/24 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto kernel scope link src 192.168.233.147 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root        8740       1  0 18:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Xiaomi Inc.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS + ADB)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.5.0-28-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:05:00.4-usb-0:1:1.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     lann
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       18deb0f1-b0c2-4e36-a5b3-a1ce9fee5f59
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.233.147/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.233.117
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.233.117, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 192.168.233.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.233.117
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.233.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 3599
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.233.117
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.233.117
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        expiry = 1715694693
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        host_name = hp
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        ip_address = 192.168.233.147
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        next_server = 192.168.233.117
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       routers = 192.168.233.117
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::1fc1:6e89:6531:59dc/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/56
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   18deb0f1-b0c2-4e36-a5b3-a1ce9fee5f59 | lann

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtw89_8852ae
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.5.0-28-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlo1' [IF3]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          50 (connecting (configuring))
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlo1
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:03:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     15note8p 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       f1c0d34a-a038-4f0a-9bf8-fa2b48d7d8f6
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/9
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               no
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/17,/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/30,/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/47,/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/83
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   6c654396-e3cc-43d5-bca2-d03b0b1a6b54 | Hotspot
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   439e5f27-7c40-4dfe-bb1d-61255d8124c5 | Wi-Fi connection 1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[3]:   63c89e16-753c-43a9-af37-b6efd7a26c30 | MyHotspot
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[4]:   f1c0d34a-a038-4f0a-9bf8-fa2b48d7d8f6 | 15note8p 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi-p2p
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifiP2P
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/1
GENERAL.PATH:                           --
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.5.0-28-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/net/eno1
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:02:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID      BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 
15note8p  <MAC '15note8p' [AN1]>  Infra  36    5180 MHz  135 Mbit/s  95      ▂▄▆█  WPA2      no             

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/30-mac-randomization.conf]]
[device-mac-randomization]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=true
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
[keyfile]

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eno1      no frequency information.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no frequency information.

wlo1      32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlo1      No scan results

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.5.0-28-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           wl
vermagic:       6.5.0-28-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.5.0-28-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       6.5.0-28-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.5.0-28-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       6.5.0-28-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 wd_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/RTL8852AE.conf]
options RTL8852AE fwlps=N

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   59.084147] wlo1: send auth to <MAC '15note8p' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[   59.099250] wlo1: send auth to <MAC '15note8p' [AN1]> (try 2/3)
[   59.114062] wlo1: send auth to <MAC '15note8p' [AN1]> (try 3/3)
[   59.129020] wlo1: authentication with <MAC '15note8p' [AN1]> timed out
[   71.383270] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC '15note8p' [AN1]>
[   71.512702] wlo1: send auth to <MAC '15note8p' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[   71.527963] wlo1: send auth to <MAC '15note8p' [AN1]> (try 2/3)
[   71.542960] wlo1: send auth to <MAC '15note8p' [AN1]> (try 3/3)
[   71.557945] wlo1: authentication with <MAC '15note8p' [AN1]> timed out


The messages indicate authorisation problems. Check your routes, ID, passwords, ports, etc.

It could be caused by wifi power management, uninstall the Broadcom driver
